# FullCalendar remove drag bars from Agenda Week Event

Tags: php, javascript, json, fullcalendar

I am using FUllCalendar and really enjoy it. I am using the agenda week view primarily to display many single events that have a half hour time slot generated by JSON. I dont want the user to be able to drag the events time down with the = bar that is at the bottom of each event. is there any way to remove this drag bar from the event. it basically looks like an equals sign at the bottom of each event like =. I cant see anywhere in the documentation that this is possible?

Comment: Which full calendar plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [eventResize](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResize/) event that you can pass in. Just make the callback call the revert function. You could also just add to your css `.ui-resizable-handle { display:none }`. I would suggest both just to make sure.

Comment: I have already tried .ui-resizable-handle { display:none; !important; } which still does not remove the = for some reason. Im not sure what you are saying about the eventResize calling the revert function. I need to have the = gone as well so its not part of the event.

Comment: eventResize is called when an event is resized like you are needing. if you pass in a callback to eventResize when you initialize full calendar, one of the arguments passed in is a revert function that you call to cancel the resize something like `eventResize:function(a,b,c,revert){revert();}`. As for the css, you need to make sure to have the style tag after all the external link tags. Also, view the resize handle in developer tools to see if/why display:none is being overridden.

Comment: Caught myself.... .ui-resizable-handle { display:none !important; } Need to remove the semicolon in the center...Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [disableResizing](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/disableResizing/); see also [editable](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/editable/).